# Error when enabling migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
namespace Healthcare
{
    public class Doc
    {
        public int DocId { get; set; }
        public string DocName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Place { get; set; }

        public List<DocContract> DocContract { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocContract
    {
        public int DocId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public Doc Doc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to enable migrations Im getting the following error:

> Healthcare.DocContract: : EntityType 'DocContract' has no key defined.
>   Define the key for this EntityType.

How can I solve this error? Basically every doc has one contract

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Here one-to-one relation is shown, where `DocContract` is dependent:

```
public class Doc
{
    public int DocId { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    public virtual DocContract DocContract { get; set; }
}

public class DocContract
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Doc")]
    public int DocId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Doc Doc { get; set; }
}
```